# Group PCA chart by specific characters in column names

Tags: r

I have been given a data set with rows having the gene names and the column names being the genotype of the samples. Column names contain genotype of species and also their treatment (either A or B). How do I plot this in a PCA graph in R by their treatment?

Currently, I have made the matrix I need yet am completely stuck how to proceed. I have made a pca plot using:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggfortify)
df<- RGenes #RGenes being what i named my matrix
pca_res2<-prcomp(df,scale.=TRUE)
autopilot(pca_res2)
```

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with, including a sample of data we can work with

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier with sample data... but, for start, you have to put additional arguments into autopilot(). add your original data (data =df) and add colour (colour = treatment)... I don't have your data, so I assume you named the treatment variable "treatment".

FIRST SEPARATE YOUR COLUMN INTO 2 COLUMNS:

```
library(dplyr) #required library

#data
test <- data.frame(val= c("ABX_102K", "ABX_102L",  "ABO_100K" , "ABO_101L"))

#seperation 
test <- test %>% separate(val, into=c("val", "treatment"), sep = -1)
```

After this follow the instructions above.

Comment: Hi @Bloxx sorry I should have provided some sample data my bad. So my sample data is as follows (apologies am new so my formatting may be poor).

here is an example: 

ABO_100K / ABO_101L / ABX_102K / ABX_102L

these are example column headers and below them would be the rows. my issue is that each column is unique and i don't know how to colour and group by each treatment which is denoted by either K or L?

Comment: in that case you have to first create new variable treatment... I will edit my first answer.